# OpenWhisk Python action failing with not returning dictionary error

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, openwhisk, ibm-cloud-functions

I am trying to run this function with OpenWhisk:

```
def main():
    return {"payload": "Hello world"}
```

With the following:

```
> bx wsk action create hello_python hello_python.py
> bx wsk action invoke hello_python
```

When running the function locally a dictionary is returned, but running the above gives this error:

```
"result": {
        "error": "The action did not return a dictionary."
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
def main(args):
    return {"payload": "Hello world"}
```

[The Python actions consume and produce a dictionary](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/openwhisk/openwhisk_actions.html#creating-python-actions). Thus you need the "args".

Comment: That looks exactly the same to what I had, is the args missing from `def main(args)`. Thanks for the link to the docs!

Comment: Sorry, when I copied your code, I forgot to add the "args". Now the answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

main() input can't be empty takes a dict like main(args)

```
def main(args):
    return {"payload": "Hello world"}
```